# How do i plot 2 separate average lines on my residuals between different x values - python

Tags: python, line, average

In the residual plot resulting from the below code, there is  substantial drop in values around the halfway point

I would like to help visualise this for those less statistically inclined by plotting 2 average lines of the residual plot
one from x(0, 110)
and the second from x(110, 240)

Here is the code

```
FINAL LINEAR MODEL

x = merged[['Imp_Col_LNG', 'AveSH_LNG']].values
y = merged['Unproductive_LNG'].values


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)

# plt.scatter(x, y)

yp=reg.predict(x)
# plt.plot(xp,yp)
# plt.text(x.max()*0.7,y.max()*0.1,'$R^2$ = 
{score:.4f}'.format(score=reg.score(x,y)))
# plt.show()

plt.scatter(yp, y)

s = yp.argsort()
plt.plot(yp[s], yp[s],color='k',ls='--') 

from scipy.stats import norm
ub = yp + norm.ppf(0.5+0.95/2) * res.std(ddof=1)
lb = yp - norm.ppf(0.5+0.95/2) * res.std(ddof=1)

plt.plot(yp[s], ub[s],color='k',ls='--')
plt.plot(yp[s], lb[s],color='k',ls='--')


plt.text(x.max()*0.7,y.max()*0.1,'$R^2$ = 
{score:.4f}'.format(score=reg.score(x,y)))

plt.xlabel('Predicted Values')
plt.ylabel('Observed Values')
plt.title('LNG_Shuffles')

plt.show()


RESIDUAL PLOTS

res = pd.Series(y - yp)
checkresiduals(res)
plt.plot(res)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you perhaps expand a little bit more on your question? Maybe clarify the average lines part a bit more?

Comment: so this a residual plot of a linear regression of total moves and density against unproductive moves - as you can see, there is a large drop in the residual values around the 110 x point - what i would like to do is draw a horizontal average line for each half of the residual plot to help re-enforce the point of the drop in values at this point

Comment: So you are doing a linear regression from 0 to 110 and from 110 to 240?

Comment: The plot is a residual from the linear regression i did comparing total moves and density to unproductive moves apologies for not making that clear - i would like to display a 2-part average line to demonstrate the drop in residual values at the 110 x point as i need to create a presentation for some people that are not data oriented and the standard residual plot while for me i can see the drop, they could not

Comment: So, you want to plot a horizontal line for each part at `y = average`? I also recommend adding this information to your question as it will help others help you in a way that's more suitable for your needs.

Comment: Yes but i am unsure how to average the y values as they are simply labelled "res" - here is the code
                    [  yp = reg.predict(x) ]      
                                  [   res = y - yp   ]
                                           [    plt.plot(res)  ]

Comment: It might be helpful to see your code so far so we know what exactly you have already.

Comment: Have attached to question - apologies am new to this

Comment: I don't seem to be able to see the code. Has the post been updated yet?

Comment: update now posted thanks for your patience - it made me delete the images however as i do not have the reputation :(

Comment: Could you convert `res` to a NumPy array and average from there for each slice of the array? Then you could do `plt.plot(np.arange(110), np.array([first_average]*110)` and `plt.plot(np.arange(110, 240), np.array([second_average]*130)`

Comment: how do i convert res to a numpy array?

Comment: `res.to_numpy()`

Comment: i am getting an error:  File "<ipython-input-57-c6175bbf40f5>", line 3
    np.array([first_average]*110)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Have you defined first_average? `first_average = np.mean(res.to_numpy()[:110])` and then do the same with second_average.

Comment: that worked! thankyou Arvin great help, apologies for being so difficult am very new to all this python and am at a fairly basic level

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I'm just going to format this all into an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are trying to plot the average of the residuals from (0, 110) and (110, 240), we first have to calculate the averages for each section.

Here, `res` stores the residual data in the form of a `pd.Series` object. To get the array information from it, we can use the `to_numpy` method of the `pd.Series` objects.

`res_data = res.to_numpy()`

Now, let's calculate the mean for each part.

```
first_average = res_data[:110].mean()
second_average = res_data[110:].mean()
```

Now, since we are going to plot this over two different ranges, we will have to convert these to numpy arrays before plotting.

```
plt.plot(np.arange(110), np.ones(110) * first_average)
plt.plot(np.arange(110, 240), np.ones(130) * second_average)
```

This should give you the piecewise residual average plot.